# List Files of Remote Directory

Tags: java

I have to dynamically select a file from a remote location based on the regular expression.

I used

```
FileUtils.listFiles(fileDirectory ,new RegexFileFilter("(" A.*")"),DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY)
```

to list the files , this fails as it says that the parameter directory is not a directory.

I understand that the it is looking on the local system for the directory , Can anybody tell me as to how can I connect to the remote machine and list the files at that location

If it is a complex task , can anybody please suggest a simple way to search for a file present on the remote location using regex.

Thanks 
Vivek

Comment: BY what protocol is your remote directory accesible? ftp? ssh? is it mounted locally?

Comment: the remote system is a Linux system , so I think I could use either the FTP or ssh protocol.

Comment: for ssh you can use http://www.jcraft.com/jsch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java), for ftp - http://commons.apache.org/net/ (http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: @dchekmarev
Thanks a lot for the suggestions. The Jsch worked like a charm... once again thanks a lot..
Can you put this in an answer to the question so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for ssh you can use jcraft.com/jsch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java), for ftp - commons.apache.org/net (http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)